# JavaScript constructor and melonJS questions

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, melonjs

I'm following this [MelonJS](http://melonjs.github.io/tutorial/) tutorial. I'm getting familiar with OOP- classes, constructors, etc... I have some questions about constructors.

In the following code snippet...

1) is `init` a melonJS special function (I read thru API, http://melonjs.github.io/docs/me.ObjectEntity.html, doesn't seem to be melon), or JavaScript? It seems to be called automatically when the playerEntity is created... what is calling `init`?

2) It seems sometimes `this` is called (`this.setVelocity`), sometimes `me` is called (`me.game.viewport.follow`). When do you call each?

3) For velocity, why do you need to multiply `accel * timer tick`? : `this.vel.x -= this.accel.x * me.timer.tick;`

```
    /*------------------- 
a player entity
-------------------------------- */
game.PlayerEntity = me.ObjectEntity.extend({

    /* -----

    constructor

    ------ */

    init: function(x, y, settings) {
        // call the constructor
        this.parent(x, y, settings);

        // set the default horizontal & vertical speed (accel vector)
        this.setVelocity(3, 15);

        // set the display to follow our position on both axis
        me.game.viewport.follow(this.pos, me.game.viewport.AXIS.BOTH);

    },

    /* -----

    update the player pos

    ------ */
    update: function() {

        if (me.input.isKeyPressed('left')) {
            // flip the sprite on horizontal axis
            this.flipX(true);
            // update the entity velocity
            this.vel.x -= this.accel.x * me.timer.tick;
        } else if (me.input.isKeyPressed('right')) {
```

Answer (score 1):

`init` is a constructor - every object that is created with the Object.extend() method will implement an interface that defines an `init` method.

As for the `this` vs. `me` - see the [documentation](http://melonjs.github.io/docs/window.me.html):

- `me` refers to the melonJS game engine - so all melonJS functions are
  defined in the `me` namespace.
- `this` is going to refer to whatever `this` is in the given context. 
  For example, in your code snippet provided, it would refer to the
  instance of the player entity.